# How to structure data in Firebase to avoid N+1 selects?

Tags: firebase

Since Firebase security rules cannot be used to filter children, what's the best way to structure data for efficient queries in a basic multi-user application? I've read through several guides, but they seem to break down when scaled past the examples given.

Say you have a basic messaging application like WhatsApp. Users can open chats with other groups of users to send private messages between themselves. Here's my initial idea of how this could be organized in Firebase (a bit similar to [this example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-revisiting-advanced-example) from the docs):

```
{
    users: {
        $uid: {
            name: string, 
            chats: {
                $chat_uid : true, 
                $chat2_uid: true
            }
        }
    },
    chats: {
        $uid: {
            messages: {
                message1: 'first message', 
                message2: 'another message'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Firebase permissions could be set up to only let users read `chats` that are marked `true` in their user object (and restrict adding arbitrarily to the `chats` object, etc).

However this layout requires N+1 selects for several common scenarios. For example: to build the home screen, the app has to first retrieve the user's `chats` object, then make a `get` request for each thread to get its info. Same thing if a user wants to search their conversations for a specific string: the app has to run a separate request for every chat they have access to in order to see if it matches.

I'm tempted to set up a node.js server to run root-authenticated queries against the `chats` tree and skip the client-side firebase code altogether. But that's defeating the purpose of Firebase in the first place.

Is there a way to organize data like this using Firebase permissions and avoid the N+1 select problem?

Comment: I'm finding the same problem for just about every scenario, to the point that I'm starting to wonder if Firebase was designed to handle n+1 queries and perhaps we shouldn't be worrying about it.  This [official blog post about denormalising data](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html) seems to suggest doing n+1 (see the example under 'Now you can simply fetch the list of comments for any given link and render them:'), as does the [firefeed.io sample app](https://firefeed.io/about.html), see the example under 'Application logic'.  /notsure

Answer (score 4):

It appears that n+1 queries do not necessarily need to be avoided and that Firebase is engineered specifically to offer good performance when doing n+1 selects, despite being counter-intuitive for developers coming from a relational database background.

An example of n+1 in the [Firebase 2.4.2 documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html) is followed by a reassuring message:

```
// List the names of all Mary's groups
var ref = new Firebase("https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/web/org");

// fetch a list of Mary's groups
ref.child("users/mchen/groups").on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  // for each group, fetch the name and print it
  String groupKey = snapshot.key();
  ref.child("groups/" + groupKey + "/name").once('value', function(snapshot) {
    System.out.println("Mary is a member of this group: " + snapshot.val());
  });
});
```

> Is it really okay to look up each record individually? Yes. The Firebase protocol uses web sockets, and the client libraries do a great deal of internal optimization of incoming and outgoing requests. Until we get into tens of thousands of records, this approach is perfectly reasonable. In fact, the time required to download the data (i.e. the byte count) eclipses any other concerns regarding connection overhead.